# Can I hide the getter and setter methods in the UML2's view?

Tags: eclipse, uml, class-diagram

UML2 is a plugin of eclipse, it's here http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/?project=uml2

Now, I want to hide the getters and setters, but I don't know how to get it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

At the UML metamodel level, there is no "getter" or setter".

So even if you somehow reverse-engineered your Java Code and end up with an UML representation, each `getXXX()` and `setXXX()` represent legitimate *services* that the GUI (like the [MDT-UML2Tools](http://wiki.eclipse.org/MDT-UML2Tools)) won't hide.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The show hide compartment was an RSA feature available in RSA 6 and later releases which has been also implemented by Omondo with EclipseUML 2008. I don't think free tools have such advanced features.

Comment: Does your UML plugin have this feature? I don't think so. The "Operation Compartment" option hides all methods.

Comment: But I only want to hide the getters and setters.

Answer (score 0):

This getters and setters should not be displayed in the diagram, 
I agree it has no modeling value. Hidding all methods with the show hide compartment is not also an acceptable solution.
Just unselect show association member for methods or even attributes in the class diagram preferences contextual menu. I tried it this morning and it works well :-)